MPI4py installation fails for python=3.8
I've been tryin to install mpi4py library within my Conda environment of python version 3.8.
I'm getting the following error message while installing through pip
  Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for mpi4py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [148 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_src
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/bench.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/dl.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/run.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/MPI.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/libmpi.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/include
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.MPI_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi4py.i -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/include/mpi4py/mpi.pxi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/include/mpi4py
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/__main__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_core.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/_lib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/aplus.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/pool.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/futures/server.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/futures
      copying src/mpi4py/util/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/dtlib.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/util
      copying src/mpi4py/util/pkl5.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/util
      running build_clib
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      checking for library 'lmpe' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -llmpe -o _configtest
      /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -llmpe: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'mpe' dylib library
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/mpe.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/mpe.o
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/lib-pmpi
      gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -L/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wl,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/mpe.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/lib-pmpi/libmpe.so
      checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -lvt-mpi -o _configtest
      /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lvt-mpi: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -lvt.mpi -o _configtest
      /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lvt.mpi: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt' dylib library
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/vt.o
      gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -L/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wl,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/vt.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/lib-pmpi/libvt.so
      checking for library 'vt-mpi' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -lvt-mpi -o _configtest
      /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lvt-mpi: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.mpi' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -lvt.mpi -o _configtest
      /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lvt.mpi: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt-mpi' dylib library
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.o
      gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -L/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wl,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/vt-mpi.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/lib-pmpi/libvt-mpi.so
      checking for library 'vt-hyb' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -lvt-hyb -o _configtest
      /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lvt-hyb: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      checking for library 'vt.ompi' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -lvt.ompi -o _configtest
      /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lvt.ompi: No such file or directory
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      building 'vt-hyb' dylib library
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.o
      gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -L/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wl,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/lib-pmpi/vt-hyb.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/lib-pmpi/libvt-hyb.so
      running build_ext
      MPI configuration: [mpi] from 'mpi.cfg'
      checking for dlopen() availability ...
      checking for header 'dlfcn.h' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/include/python3.8 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      success!
      checking for library 'dl' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/include/python3.8 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38 -ldl -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
      checking for function 'dlopen' ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/include/python3.8 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ _configtest.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38 -ldl -o _configtest
      success!
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
      building 'mpi4py.dl' extension
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DHAVE_DLOPEN=1 -I/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/include/python3.8 -c src/dynload.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/dynload.o
      gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -L/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/dynload.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38 -ldl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/mpi4py/dl.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      checking for MPI compile and link ...
      gcc -pthread -B /home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/syerawar_umass_edu/.conda/envs/DiffusionLM/include/python3.8 -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
      _configtest.c:2:10: fatal error: mpi.h: No such file or directory
          2 | #include <mpi.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      failure.
      removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
      error: Cannot compile MPI programs. Check your configuration!!!
      [end of output]

How should I progress on solving this mpi4py installation issue?

Have you tried installing using conda: conda install conda-forge::mpi4py

This issue is likely caused due to python depreciated dependencies. You can try installing the library like this:
Python 3.8.0
(env) PS C:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\test> pip install --no-cache-dir  mpi4py
Collecting mpi4py
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/9d/cce868ab0f5f983555204bbf8b61bd770742d1231b8f7050671726f8d8bc/mpi4py-3.1.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (480kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 481kB 3.3MB/s
Installing collected packages: mpi4py
Successfully installed mpi4py-3.1.6```

